# How to implement RGBA in 8-bit microcontroller?

Tags: hardware, color

I have successfully connected my microcontroller to my TV via through VGA adapter i made that convert digital to analog signals with the help of resistors.

Currently i am utilizing 8 pins that I am using as 2 Red 2 Green 2 Blue 1 Hsyn and 1 Vsyn. I was thinking if there is a way to add 'A' Alpha in it, it's used for transparency. My another question is that is Alpha software driven or is it in the hardware?

Apparently, i did not find any relevant resources on hardware side of RGBA. I did notice Gameduino has used it in their 16-bit microcontroller. Is it possible to use multiplexing/charlieplexing in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your going to need to support your Alpha channel in software. If you have 3 bytes for RGB you will need an extra Alpha byte to represent the transparency of the pixel in your source images.

The blending comes in to play when you composite all the layers on top of one another.

To blend you will need a screen size buffer in memory that you copy each object on to.

You didn't mention what language your using but if it is C you can convert your alpha to a percentage that you can use to blend with

```
float alpha = pixel.alpha / 255;
buffer[offset_dst].R += pixel[offset_src].R * alpha;
buffer[offset_dst].G += pixel[offset_src].G * alpha;
buffer[offset_dst].B += pixel[offset_src].B * alpha;
```

Obviously that code is for illustration only, you will quickly saturate your buffers pixels with a few layers using this. Note you don't need an Alpha channel in the buffer.

Anyway once you have drawn all your elements to the buffer send the buffer to your TV.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to support in in hardware? Does vendors have it built in into the hardware or its always been software? Just a thought, is multiplexing is a way to go? And i am using Assembly but i guess it will probably be more easier to work in C. I choose Assembly just because i could squeeze a bit more power out of it. Legitimately, i will be putting up some animations as a demo so we'll see. THANKS!

Comment: Alpha blending can be done 'in hardware' by a powerful OpenGL or Direct3D graphics card. It involves a lot of copying of things and large buffers. It is supported by 3D capable graphics cards as they are already doing most of the steps involved in alpha blending. If it is to be done in hardware it has to take place before the signal is sent over the wire I would assume. In short even a graphics card that supports alpha blending still sends an RGB signal to the monitor, not an RGBA one.

Comment: As for the C verses Assembler debate. I think, if you are starting out, Assembler will give you a very good deep understanding of how hardware works ( something missing from more day to day software developers these days ). Most developers of higher level languages I know would not understand bit level logic, masks and so on. I moved towards and learned C when the Assembler became to hard to manage ( and that is quickly ) - Compilers are so good these days that you will have little performance advantage hand coding in Assembler and as a bonus most compilers allow inline assembler code.

Comment: The lines between what is software and what is hardware are more blurred these days ( Google FPGA ). At any rate I think the methods I outlined are valid considering you are using custom hardware.

Comment: I agree there are compilers that will optimize the C code. There are now specific machine instructions that are built for higher level languages but i believe Assembly is great for microcontroller programming. I will learn the inner-workings of the software-hardware connection as you mentioned. As far as FPGA go, i don't want to go that road. I guess my upper comment was sidetracked a bit, another question i wanted to ask was "My pin configuration will not change regardless of Alpha?" i think Will answered that. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Yeah your hardware will not change. It's down to pure coding grunt work from here on out.

Comment: I give one up's to the both of you. Thank you so much! It helps to have a community like stackexchange around.